# Why are threads messing up?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, thread-sleep

i started learning kotlin Coroutines. But I am facing a situation like this.

```
fun main(){

    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread started")

    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread started")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread finished")
    }


    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread started")
        delay(1000)
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread finished")
    }

    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread started")
        delay(1000)
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread finished")
    }


    runBlocking {
        delay(1000)
    }
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} thread finished")
}
```

the output of this code:

```
main thread started
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread started
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread started
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 thread started
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread finished
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread finished
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread finished
main thread finished
```

Why "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread finished" is running 2 times.
I guess it's just the threads' names are changing, but I'm wondering why ?

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines provide no guarantee that the whole coroutine will run on the same thread for its whole duration. Thread management is handled by the dispatchers you use. Dispatchers.Default uses a thread pool and can swap threads each time it resumes from suspension, as it does after each `delay()` call. This is intended behavior, as it can reduce the total number of spawned Thread objects.